# NSDateComponent giving me day incremented by 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I know this is a time zone problem, but I don't know how to solve this.

I have a `NSDate = 2013-07-29 01:10:01 +0000`

When I do a `NSDateComponent`, the day component shows `28`!

I'm in `EST` time zone right now, but why doesn't it just show `29` straight up??  Is this a bug?

If not, how do i fix this to show it properly?  Or is it already proper?

Thanks.

Comment: `EST` time zone offset: `UTC` - 5 hours, so it's `2013-07-28 20:10:01` in `EST` time zone when `2013-07-29 01:10:01` in `UTC` time zone

Comment: July is E _D_ T, which is GMT/UTC -4, but other than that @AndreyGordeev is correct, and your date is "proper". The `NSDate` is displayed in GMT unless you format it, but the moment in time it represents is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your calendar instance is currently set to your time zone, so it is interpreting the date as 5 hours prior to what it would be in GMT (which is what you pasted in  your question).

To resolve this issue you should set the `timeZone` property on the calendar you are using to get the date components out of the date.  Something like this will probably do the trick, assuming your calendar variable is named `calendar`:

```
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```